# How to create event response with Node 12 for AWS Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, async-await

The tutorial I am looking at is using, Node 6.1 for AWS Lambda function

```
export.fn = (event,context,callback) {
    callback(null,event)
};
```

I want to use Node.12.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from G!'),
  };
  return response;
}
```

How to rewrite my function that it can accept JSON data?

```
{
  "persondata": {
    "name": "Max",
    "length": 29
  }
}
```

Response Body

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from G!\""
}
```

Logs

```
Mon Dec 16 11:38:57 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /compare-yourself
Mon Dec 16 11:38:57 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {}
Mon Dec 16 11:38:57 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {}
Mon Dec 16 11:38:57 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
Mon Dec 16 11:38:57 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: {
   "persondata" : {
     "name" : "Max", 
     "length" : 29
   }
}
```

Comment: Your handler looks fine , you can already accept json. What issues are you facing

Comment: Take a look at my edit,there is no JSON response. Logs recognize them.

Comment: I dont still understand, you are returning `Hello from G!` then why are you expecting a json response

Comment: Ok, I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a json from lambda as below:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "persondata": {
        "name": "Max",
        "length": 29
      }
    })
  };
  return response;
}
```

Comment: I didn't initially follow you, sorry about that